# PHP Mailer: Showing white screen with text / server response only when attaching files

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

I was testing sending emails from a local project (using laravel and PHP Mailer) and everything works fine, I can actually send the emails with the attachments and everything looks good, my only issue is that when I send attached files from the form it shows for a few seconds a kind of weird white page with for me looks like google response from sending the message.

[image: no description]

My function looks like this:

```php
public function send($request) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
        // All the other mail information needed

        if ($request->hasFile('attachment')) {
            $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
        }

        $mail->send();
        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'msg' => 'Email sent!'
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            'msg' => 'Something went wrong. Details: '. $mail->ErrorInfo
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

If I have no file to attach -i mean, we don't get inside the 'if'- it doesn't show the response screen, but I am not sure if there is something in code I can do to avoid showing it.
Even If I put no info in the return or I write no return at all, the screen keeps showing.

I followed several videos and read the documentation of PHP Mailer, followed the steps and everything works, but no place mention something like this

Comment: If you are using Laravel and a `Request`, NEVER use `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_FILES`, etc.... Use the `$request`.....

Comment: What you’re seeing is debug output. Turn it off by not setting `SMTPDebug`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you so much for your feedback. I was having issues with that getting a loadingFiles class error, and even following others steps couldn't solve it, but I'll try to find the right answer :)

Comment: @Synchro Thanks a lot, didn't know the meaning of that line, I'll read more about it, but so far solved the thing!